# How to print thread id of all threads a process on linux has

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I know how to print thread id while executing in the context of a thread, but I would like to print all thread ids that a process has spawned. I need this to correlate with strace output for debugging.

How to get current thread id:
 pid_t x = syscall(__NR_gettid);

Answer (score 1):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/901/134332

For each process, a lot of information is available in `/proc/12345` where `12345` is the process ID. Information on each thread is available in `/proc/12345/task/67890` where `67890` is the kernel thread ID. This is where ps, top and other tools get their information.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the virtual `/proc` filesystem. Iterate over the dirnames in `/proc/self/task`.

```
if(DIR* dir = opendir("/proc/self/task")) {
    while (dirent* entry = readdir(dir))
        if (entry->d_name[0] != '.')
            std::cout << entry->d_name;
    closedir(dir);
}
```